# ¿Cómo manejar un ciclo foreach dentro de otros foreach para elementos del localstorage?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que pintar la información que almacene en el localstorage pero al intentar pintar la opción de colores que es un array, esta se empieza a multiplicar dentro de todos los elementos siguiente. ejemplo si el primer elemento tiene 3 colores y el segundo tiene 2. al primer elemento se le pintan los 3 de el pero al segun se le pintan todos los 5 así con todos los elementos. Esto solo pasa al momento de ser pintados porque los elementos están bien almacenados. Añado una imagen de lo que se pinta en pantalla con el código de consola y el código que estoy manejando. Gracias por la colaboración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//console.log('Script Conectado')
//Variables
const listaProductos = document.querySelector('#lista-productos tbody')
const inputContent = document.querySelector('input[name="product"]')
let Cotizacion = []
let item = {id:'',nombre:'',img:'',cantidad:1}

//console.log(arrayCotizacion)  

//Functions
const CrearItem = (id,nombre,img,colores) => {
    let item = {id:id,nombre:nombre,img:img,colores:colores,cantidad:1}
    Cotizacion.push(item)
    return item
}

const GuardarLS = () => {       
    localStorage.setItem('cotizacion-valnic',JSON.stringify(Cotizacion))
    PintarLS()
}

const PintarLS = () => {
listaProductos.innerHTML = ''
Cotizacion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cotizacion-valnic'))
let template = document.querySelector('#template-producto').content
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
//console.log(template)
if(Cotizacion === null) {
    Cotizacion = []
} else {
        Cotizacion.forEach( envase => { 
            console.log(envase)                 
            template.querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="'+envase.img+'" width="70px">'
            template.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent = envase.nombre
            envase.colores.forEach( color => {
                console.log(color)          
                let id = envase.id
                if(envase.id === id) {
                    console.log('los id son iguales')
                    console.log(color + '-' + id)
                    template.querySelector('.colores').innerHTML += '<div style="background-color:#'+color+';width: 20px;height: 20px;border-radius: 50%; margin:5px;"></div>'
                }
            })
            let clone = template.cloneNode(true)
            fragment.appendChild(clone)
        })
        listaProductos.appendChild(fragment)
    }
//console.log(Cotizacion)       
}

const EliminarLS = (nombre) => {
    //console.log(actividad)
    let indexArray = Cotizacion.findIndex((elemento) => {
        return elemento.nombre === nombre
    })
    Cotizacion.splice(indexArray, 1)
    GuardarLS()
}

const EditarLS = (nombre) => {
    //otra forma de hacer el mismo ciclo de EliminarLS
    let indexArray = Cotizacion.findIndex((elemento) => {
        return elemento.nombre === nombre
    })
    //console.log(arrayActividades[indexArray])
    Cotizacion[indexArray].cantidad = Cotizacion[indexArray].cantidad + 1;
    GuardarLS()
}

const contenidoEmail = () => {
    Cotizacion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cotizacion-valnic'))
    Cotizacion.forEach(envase => {
        let contenido = '{' + 'Nombre: ' + envase.nombre + ' Colores: ' + envase.colores + '}, '
        inputContent.value += contenido
    })      
}

//EvenListener  
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', PintarLS)
    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contenidoEmail)

listaProductos.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(e)
        if(e.target.innerHTML === 'done' || e.target.innerHTML === 'delete') {
                let text = e.path[0].innerHTML
                if(e.target.innerHTML === 'delete') {
                        EliminarLS(text)
                }
                if(e.target.innerHTML === 'done') {
                        EditarLS(text)
                }
        }
})
```

Comment: Estás modificando directamente la plantilla, por eso aparecen elementos que no corresponden. Debes clonar la plantilla, trabajar con el elemento clonado y agregarlo a la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuestas. Pero tienes algún ejemplo de esto para poder guiarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dije en comentario: Estás modificando directamente la plantilla, por eso aparecen elementos que no corresponden. Debes clonar la plantilla, trabajar con el elemento clonado y agregarlo a la lista.

```
const PintarLS = () => {
    listaProductos.innerHTML = ''
    Cotizacion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cotizacion-valnic'))
    let template = document.querySelector('#template-producto').content
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()

    if(Cotizacion === null) {
        Cotizacion = []
    } else {
        Cotizacion.forEach( envase => { 
            console.log(envase)
            // Clonar la plantilla, para mantenerla sin modificar
            let clone = template.cloneNode(true)
            // Trabajar con el elemento clonado
            clone.querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="'+envase.img+'" width="70px">'
            clone.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent = envase.nombre
            envase.colores.forEach( color => {
                console.log(color)
                let id = envase.id
                // El if sale sobrando, id siempre será igual a envase.id
                // porque lo acabas de asignar en la línea anterior
                // if(envase.id === id) {
                    console.log('los id son iguales')
                    console.log(color + '-' + id)
                    clone.querySelector('.colores').innerHTML += '<div style="background-color:#'+color+';width: 20px;height: 20px;border-radius: 50%; margin:5px;"></div>'
                // }
            })
            // Agregas el elemento clonado
            fragment.appendChild(clone)
        })
        listaProductos.appendChild(fragment)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso era lo que necesitaba.